# Probability of two or more events given, find rate of Poisson Process

Tags: probability

I'm given that the probability of  two or more events happening in a given  time period is 28%, and asked to  find  the rate of the underlying  Poisson process.

Not  quite  sure how to proceed. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: The probability that fewer than two events occur is 72%.  This is the probability that no event occurs or that exactly one event occurs.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+exp(-lambda)*(1%2Blambda)%3D.72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the number of events that occur in the given time period

As saulspatz pointed out

$$P(T\geq 2)=0.28 \iff P(T\lt2)=P(T=0)+P(T=1)=0.72$$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
0.72
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^0}{0!}+\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^1}{1!}\\\\
&=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}\\\\
&=e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

We now have an equation with one unknown. You must solve for $\lambda$

Comment: solving we get 

λ = 1.04825

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-a)+(1+%2Ba)+%3D+0.72